# Tracking profile Implementation Visibility attribute has no impact?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

We're creating rather large workflow services so, to make things more clean, we've decided to "split them" into sub-activities.

This, on it's own, works quite well.

However, we've noticed that events aren't being tracked any more - only events from the actual workflow are tracked, while events from the part activities are omitted (unless something throws an exception and crashes).

I've read up [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513989%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and I see I was missing the `implementationVisibility` property - by default it's set to the root scope of the workflow.

So I've created a custom tracking profile, defined as such:

```
<trackingProfile name="CRM Game HealthMonitoring Tracking Profile" implementationVisibility="All">
  <workflow activityDefinitionId="*">
    <workflowInstanceQueries>
      <workflowInstanceQuery>
        <states>
          <state name="Started" />
          <state name="UnhandledException" />
          <state name="Persisted" />
          <state name="Unsuspended" />
          <state name="Aborted" />
          <state name="Canceled" />
          <state name="Completed" />
          <state name="Terminated" />
        </states>
      </workflowInstanceQuery>
    </workflowInstanceQueries>
    <activityStateQueries>
      <activityStateQuery activityName="*">
        <states>
          <state name="Closed" />
        </states>
      </activityStateQuery>
    </activityStateQueries>
    <customTrackingQueries>
      <customTrackingQuery name="*" activityName="*" />
    </customTrackingQueries>
    <faultPropagationQueries>
      <faultPropagationQuery faultSourceActivityName="*" faultHandlerActivityName="*" />
    </faultPropagationQueries>
    <bookmarkResumptionQueries>
      <bookmarkResumptionQuery name="*" />
    </bookmarkResumptionQueries>
  </workflow>
</trackingProfile>
```

I've then opened the AppFabric configuration for the specific workflow and added this profile to the configuration.

Sadly, the end-result is that tracking works exactly as before, as if the tracking profile wasn't being used at all.

EDIT: The new tracking profile IS being used because bookmark resumption events are now tracked. However, the events are still only tracked for workflow root activities.

What am I doing wrong?

PS. Is there a way to set a default tracking profile for all workflows?

EDIT 2:
According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) link there's no `implementationVisibility` parameter in the `<trackingProfile>` definition at all... What's going on?

Comment: How have you splited those activities? Are they all designed activities or coded activities also?

Comment: @Jota The split was done by copy-pasting parts of the original workflow into designed activities. As coded activities did exist previously, they have now been copied over to the parts designed "parts".

Comment: Ok. It might happen that you weren't adding some implementation activities to metadata, inside coded activities. "as if the tracking profile wasn't being used at all". Isn't it possible that configuration isn't really being used at all? Can you show more of the configuration? Have you looked at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517415(v=vs.110).aspx) already?

Comment: @Jota Please note the edit I've made to the question. What I meant by "as if the tracking profile wasn't being used" was I didn't think **MY** tracking profile was being used. Tracking, in a global sense, is working and as I wrote is tracking stuff happening in the main root workflow.

Comment: That's weird. Can't reproduce it myself and I've already tried all possible scenarios: splited XAML activities, splited coded activities, a mix of both, etc. I'm running out of ideas. It might be a problem of the TrackingParticipant itself. Play with it, for example, instead of "*", specify exactly the activityName and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know WHY this has failed, I found out that loading and setting the tracking profile via the IIS Management screen didn't work.

When I placed the entire configuration in the `web.config` file (tracking profile definition and selecting it as the default tracking profile for our workflows) then it started to work as expected.

Here's the important part of the final `web.config` if anyone's interested. :)

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <tracking>
      <profiles>
        <trackingProfile name="My Tracking Profile" implementationVisibility="All">
          <workflow activityDefinitionId="*">
            <workflowInstanceQueries>
              <workflowInstanceQuery>
                <states>
                  <state name="Started" />
                  <state name="UnhandledException" />
                  <state name="Persisted" />
                  <state name="Unsuspended" />
                  <state name="Aborted" />
                  <state name="Canceled" />
                  <state name="Completed" />
                  <state name="Terminated" />
                </states>
              </workflowInstanceQuery>
            </workflowInstanceQueries>
            <activityStateQueries>
              <activityStateQuery activityName="*">
                <states>
                  <state name="Closed" />
                </states>
              </activityStateQuery>
            </activityStateQueries>
            <customTrackingQueries>
              <customTrackingQuery name="*" activityName="*" />
            </customTrackingQueries>
            <faultPropagationQueries>
              <faultPropagationQuery faultSourceActivityName="*" faultHandlerActivityName="*" />
            </faultPropagationQueries>
          </workflow>
        </trackingProfile>
      </profiles>
    </tracking>
    <bindings />
    <client />
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <etwTracking profileName="My Tracking Profile"/>
          (...)
```